# C++ simple inheritance problem

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
protected:
    int a;
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    int func(A* p)
    {
        cout << p->a;
    }
};
```

I really cannot understand why I cant access to 'a' by 'p->a'.

Is there anyway to access p's member 'a' in class B, without changing 'protected' to 'public'?

Comment: AFAIK, you should be able to access `a`, so what compiler and os are you using? And, what messages are produced when you compile this?

Comment: Can you access just `a` instead of `p->a`?

Comment: error C2248: 'A::a' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'

Comment: I am currently using Visual Studio 2010...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On this topic, the C++03 standard states (emphasis mine):

> 11.5 Protected member access
>
> 1 When a friend or a member function of a
>   derived class references a protected nonstatic member function or
>   protected nonstatic data member of a base class, an access check
>   applies in addition to those described earlier in clause
>   11. Except when forming a pointer to member (5.3.1), **the access
>   must be through a pointer to, reference to, or object of the derived
>   class itself** (or any class derived from that class) (5.2.5).

What you are doing here, however, is trying to access through a pointer to the *base* class, which is illegal. If you change the signature to

```
int func(B* p) // instead of A*
```

you will find that it now compiles normally.

This is also the reason why you can access `a` without trouble from inside `class B`: the access is made through the implicit pointer `this`, which is of type `B*` (the derived class again). If you tried this:

```
A* parent = static_cast<A*>(this);
int x = parent->a; // Does not compile!
```

You would find that it won't compile, for the very same reason.

The converse also applies: if you downcast the pointer `p` to a `B*` you can access the `protected` member just fine:

```
class A
{
public:
    // Added virtual destructor so that the class acquires a vptr,
    // making dynamic_cast possible.
    virtual ~A() {};
protected:
    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int func(A* p)
    {
        // Now if we downcast p to B* we can access a just fine
        // Of course if p does not actually point to a B, the
        // program will have undefined behavior
        int x = dynamic_cast<B*>(p)->a;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thx a lot Jon!! C++ is getting more interesting than I thought before :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `p->a` would only let you access *public* variables of A. Since `a` is a *protected* variable, you should use `cout << a`, since `a` is inherited in class B.

I think you could use `cout << p->a` by `friend`ing class B.

Or by using a pointer to `B` instead of a pointer to `A`, as [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) noted.

Comment: It seems like friend also does not work :( I tried #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
protected:
 int a;

};
class B : public A
{
 friend class A;
public:
 int func(A* p)
 {
  cout << p->a;
 }
 
};

Comment: It's the other way around: class A: {friend class B; ...}

Comment: There is no public and protected "version" of the variable. The compiler simply does not let you access non-public members through a pointer to the base class.

Comment: @djeidot: The answer is still misleading and incomplete. `a` is not the same as `p->a`, and in fact you *can* access `p->a` from the parameter by e.g. doing a `dynamic_cast<B*>(p)->a` (although this comes with its own set of pitfalls).

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, this is a good question.  First, let me start off by saying `B` is NOT a friend of `A`, and therefore does not have access to `A`'s privates (or protected's) through an "A" view of the object.  Even though we are in the scope of class `B`, we cannot just go around looking at `A`'s privates (or protected's).

HOWEVER, B *does* have an `a`.  And it does have access to it, because it is declared a protected member of `A`.  But the only way to see `int a` inside of a `B`, is to get it from a `B` view of an object.